# Phrasing queries about doko

Tags: set-phrases

Should I use "doko wa otearai desu ka?" Or "otearai wa doko desu ka?"
Or are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

- "Otearai wa doko desu ka" is correct.
- "Doko wa otearai desu ka" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, normally you can't start your sentences with "doko wa". That would mean that you're introducing "where" as a topic/object that is being discussed, which doesn't make sense if you think about it. Your second sentence is fine, use it. :)